# Auto-indentation does not work in WebStorm

Tags: html, webstorm, indentation

Auto-indentation does not work in WebStorm.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It doesn't indent html, head, or body tags. So this is expected behavior.

Comment: @JohnConde, oh. Really. Thank you.

Comment: your code seems to be properly formatted as is, so *auto-indent* doesn't change the formatting